# SIMD: Accumulate Adjacent Pairs

Tags: c++, sse, simd, intrinsics, avx

I'm learning how to use SIMD intrinsics and autovectorization. Luckily, I have a useful project I'm working on that seems extremely amenable to SIMD, but is still tricky for a newbie like me.

I'm writing a filter for images that computes the average of 2x2 pixels. I'm doing part of the computation by accumulating the sum of two pixels into a single pixel.

```cpp
template <typename T, typename U>
inline void accumulate_2x2_x_pass(
  T* channel, U* accum,
  const size_t sx, const size_t sy, 
  const size_t osx, const size_t osy,
  const size_t yoff, const size_t oyoff
) {

  const bool odd_x = (sx & 0x01);

  size_t i_idx, o_idx;

  // Should be vectorizable somehow...
  for (size_t x = 0, ox = 0; x < sx - (size_t)odd_x; x += 2, ox++) {
    i_idx = x + yoff;
    o_idx = ox + oyoff;
    accum[o_idx] += channel[i_idx];
    accum[o_idx] += channel[i_idx + 1];
  }

  if (odd_x) {
    // << 1 bc we need to multiply by two on the edge 
    // to avoid darkening during render
    accum[(osx - 1) + oyoff] += (U)(channel[(sx - 1) + yoff]) * 2;
  }
}
```

However, godbolt shows that my loop is not autovectorizable. (https://godbolt.org/z/qZxvof) How would I construct SIMD intrinsics to solve this issue? I have control of the alignment for accum, but not channel.

(I know there's an average intrinsic, but it's not appropriate here because I need to generate multiple mip levels and that command would cause loss of precision for the next level.)

Thanks everyone. :)

Comment: Looks like a use-case for SSSE3 `_mm_hadd_epi32` or `_mm_hadd_epi16` T is `int16_t` instead of `int`.  It costs the same as 2 shuffles + a vertical add, but you need that anyway to pack 2 inputs to 1.  If you want to work around a shuffle-port bottleneck on Intel CPUs, you could consider using qword shifts on the inputs and then shuffling together the result with `shufps`.

Comment: Wow, that's pretty cool! I had been under the impression that "horizontal" operations were not possible in SIMD. I'll give this a try tomorrow. For what it's worth, the dominant use case for this operation is uint8_t -> uint16_t

Comment: In general they're not, and it's not super fast; see my update to my first comment.

Comment: I didn't realize you were widening, that changes things entirely. 
 (Also, you showed short -> int on Godbolt; what SSE/AVX version are you targeting?  You used `-march=native` on Godbolt, which is Skylake-AVX512 = AVX512BW).    Anyway, `_mm_hadd_*` isn't useful when `U` is not the same width as `T`.  You probably want `pmaddwd` or `pmaddubsw` with a multiplier of 1 to add horizontal pairs into a wider result.

Comment: I had it on -march=native to try to force autovectorization. I've been running code on Google Cloud Platform, which has mainly Haswell and later, but I was hoping random people on the internet could use it as well. I've been having good success distributing binaries sans the -march flag. Thanks for the tips. :)

Comment: I updated godbolt to better reflect the actual types. I am using size_t, but I rendered it as uint64_t on godbolt.

Comment: You should always use `-march=haswell` or similar if you know that's what you're targeting.  That sets important tuning options as well as instruction sets.  And don't use `-march=corei7`, it's kind of meaningless / confusing because it's basically `-march=nehalem` (the *first* generation of core i7).

Comment: On Godbolt you can `#include <stddef.h>` and use `size_t` like a normal person.  And notice that gcc did auto-vectorize your code for uint8_t -> uint16_t.   Not particularly *well*, but it did it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The widening case with the narrow type `T` = `uint8_t` or `uint16_t`** is probably best implemented with SSSE3 `pmaddubsw` or SSE2 `pmaddwd` with a multiplier of `1`.  ([Intrinsics guide](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#techs=SSE,SSE2,SSE3,SSSE3,SSE4_1,SSE4_2,AVX,AVX2,Other&expand=6150,6150,401,2424&text=pmadd))  Those instructions are single-uop and do exactly the horizontal widening add you need more efficiently than shuffling.

If you're horizontally summing across 8 or more u8 elements, use `psadbw` (sum of absolute differences) against a zeroed vector.  `_mm_sad_epu8` to get sums at the bottom of each 64-bit element.  (A good first step if [hsumming a whole vector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-sse-vector-sum-or-other-reduction), or summing a whole u8 array without overflow.)

**If you can do so without losing precision, do the vertical add between rows *first*, before widening horizontal add**.  (e.g. 10, 12, or 14-bit pixel components in `[u]int16_t` can't overflow).  Load and vertical-add have 2 per clock throughput (or more) on most CPUs, vs. 1 per clock for `pmadd*` only having 2-per-clock throughput on Skylake and later.  **And it means you only need 1x add + 1x pmadd vs. 2x pmadd + 1x add so it's a significant win even on Skylake.**  (For the 2nd way, both loads can fold into memory operands for pmadd, if you have AVX.  For the add before pmadd way, you'll need a pure load first and then fold the 2nd load into add, so you might not save front-end uops, unless you use indexed addressing modes and they un-laminate.)

And ideally you don't need to `+=` into an accumulator array, and instead can just read 2 rows in parallel and accumulator is write-only, so your loop has only 2 input streams and 1 output stream.

```
// SSSE3
__m128i hadd_widen8_to_16(__m128i a) {
                      // uint8_t, int8_t  (doesn't matter when multiplier is +1)
    return _mm_maddubs_epi16(a, _mm_set_epi8(1));
}

// SSE2
__m128i hadd_widen16_to_32(__m128i a) {
                   // int16_t, int16_t
    return _mm_madd_epi16(a, _mm_set_epi16(1));
}
```

These port to 256-bit AVX2 directly, because the input and output width is the same.  No shuffle needed to fix up in-lane packing.

Yes really, they're both `_epi16`.  Intel can be wildly inconsistent with intrinsic names.  asm mnemonics are more consistent and easier to remember what's what.  (`ubsw` = unsigned byte to signed word, except that one of the inputs is signed bytes.  `pmaddwd` is packed multiply add word to dword, same naming scheme as `punpcklwd` etc.)

---

**The T=U case with `uint16_t` or `uint32_t`** is a a use-case for SSSE3 `_mm_hadd_epi16` or `_mm_hadd_epi32`.  It costs the same as 2 shuffles + a vertical add, but you need that anyway to pack 2 inputs to 1.

If you want to work around a shuffle-port bottleneck on Haswell and later, you could consider using qword shifts on the inputs and then shuffling together the result with `shufps` (`_mm_shuffle_ps` + some casting).  This could possibly be a win on Skylake (with 2 per clock shift throughput), even though it costs more 5 total uops instead of 3.  It can run at best 5/3 cycles per vector of output instead of 2 cycles per vector if there's no front-end bottleneck.

```
// UNTESTED

//Only any good with AVX, otherwise the extra movdqa instructions kill this
//Only worth considering for Skylake, not Haswell (1/c shifts) or Sandybridge (2/c shuffle)
__m128i hadd32_emulated(__m128i a, __m128i b) {
    __m128i a_shift = _mm_srli_epi64(a, 32);
    __m128i b_shift = _mm_srli_epi64(b, 32);
    a = _mm_add_epi32(a, a_shift);
    b = _mm_add_epi32(b, b_shift);
    __m128 combined = _mm_shuffle_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(a), _mm_castsi128_ps(b), _MM_SHUFFLE(2,0,2,0));
    return _mm_castps_si128(combined);
}
```

Ice Lake and later Intel, and AMD, have better than 1/clock throughput for some shuffles but not all.  For example, `vphaddd` is 2 uops for p1 or p5 on Ice Lake or later, plus 1 uop for any of p015.  But `vhaddps`'s 2 shuffle uops can only run on port 5, even though you can precisely emulate `vhaddps` with 2x `vshufps` (with `_MM_SHUFFLE(2,0,2,0)` for evens and `_MM_SHUFFLE(3,1,3,1)` for odds, as shown in [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77687986/how-to-vectorize-a-vector-matrix-product-with-sse/77691715#77691715)), and `vshufps` runs on p1/p5 (unlike `vunpcklps` for some reason).  And AMD CPUs run `vhaddps` less efficiently than you'd expect as well.  So if you have a lot of pairwise summing of FP data, you might consider manually using shuffles that clang won't "optimize" into `vhaddps`.

But for integer `vphaddd` on Ice Lake / Alder Lake and Zen 3 / Zen 4, things seem ok.  At least with YMM vectors; Zen 3/4  at least take an extra uop for `vphaddd xmm, xmm, xmm` according to https://uops.info/ measurements.

---

For an AVX2 version you'd need a lane-crossing shuffle to fixup a `vphadd` result.  So emulating hadd with shifts might be a bigger win.

```
// 3x shuffle 1x add uops
__m256i hadd32_avx2(__m256i a, __m256i b) {
    __m256i hadd = _mm256_hadd_epi32(a, b);  // 2x in-lane hadd
    return _mm256_permutex_epi64( hadd, _MM_SHUFFLE(3,1,2,0) );
}

// UNTESTED
// 2x shift, 2x add, 1x blend-immediate (any ALU port), 1x shuffle
__m256i hadd32_emulated_avx2(__m256i a, __m256i b)
{
        __m256i a_shift = _mm256_srli_epi64(a, 32);  // useful result in the low half of each qword
        __m256i b_shift = _mm256_slli_epi64(b, 32);  // ... high half of each qword
        a = _mm256_add_epi32(a, a_shift);
        b = _mm256_add_epi32(b, b_shift);
        __m256i blended = _mm256_blend_epi32(a,b, 0b10101010);  // alternating low/high results
        return _mm256_permutexvar_epi32(_mm256_set_epi32(7,5,3,1, 6,4,2,0),  blended);
}
```

On Haswell and Skylake, `hadd32_emulated_avx2` can run at 1 per 2 clocks (saturating all vector ALU ports).  The extra `add_epi32` to sum into `accum[]` will slow it down to at best 7/3 cycles per 256-bit vector of results, and you'll need to unroll (or use a compiler that unrolls) to not just bottleneck on the front-end.

`hadd32_avx2` can run at 1 per 3 clocks (bottlenecked on port 5 for shuffles).  The load + store + extra `add_epi32` uops to implement your loop can run in the shadow of that easily.

(https://agner.org/optimize/, https://uops.info/, and see https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info)