# How to vectorize a vector-matrix product with SSE?

Tags: c++, matrix-multiplication, simd, sse, dot-product

I have this function in C++

```cpp
void routine2(float alpha, float beta) {

    unsigned int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
            w[i] = w[i] - beta + alpha * A[i][j] * x[j];

}
```

And this is the SSE(vectorized) version I wrote

```cpp
void routine2_vec(float alpha, float beta) {
    __m128 alpha_2 = _mm_set1_ps(alpha);
    __m128 beta_2 = _mm_set1_ps(beta);

    __m128 w2,num1,A2,X2;
    __m128 multiple1, multiple2,sub;

    unsigned int i, j;
    

    for ( i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        w2 = _mm_setzero_ps();
        for ( j = 0; j < (N/4)*4; j += 4) {
            num1 = _mm_loadu_ps(&w[i]);

            A2 = _mm_loadu_ps(&A[i][j]);
            X2 = _mm_loadu_ps(&x[j]);

            multiple1 = _mm_mul_ps(A2, X2);
            multiple2 = _mm_mul_ps(alpha_2, multiple1);
            sub = _mm_sub_ps(num1, beta_2);

            w2 = _mm_add_ps(sub, multiple2);
            _mm_store_ss(&w[i], w2);
        }

    }
}
```

The result of the both function should be the same, so I wrote another function to run and compare the result of both of them.

Test & compare functions

```cpp
int routine2_test(float alpha, float beta) {
    unsigned int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            test2[i] = test2[i] - beta + alpha * A[i][j] * x[j];

        }
    }
  
    // compare
    for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        if (equal(w[j], test2[j]) == 1) {
            printf("\n The result of w[%d] is not equal to test2[%d]  \n", j, j);
            return 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}


unsigned short int equal(float a, float b) {
    float temp = a - b;
    //printf("\n %f  %f", a, b);
    if ((fabs(temp) / fabs(b)) < EPSILON)
        return 0; //success
    else
        return 1; //wrong result
}
```

The test function runs the primary code and store the result in the `test2` array, and the `routine2_vec` function is do the same with SSE and store the result in `w` array, then I compare both results in the `routine2_test` with the `equal` function.

**EDITED**

This is remaining part including main and init functions.

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pmmintrin.h>
#include <process.h>
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <omp.h>

#define M 256*128
#define ARITHMETIC_OPERATIONS1 3*M
#define TIMES1 1

#define N  2048
#define ARITHMETIC_OPERATIONS2 4*N*N
#define TIMES2 1


constexpr auto EPSILON =0.0001;

//function declaration
void initialize();
void routine2(float alpha, float beta);

unsigned short int equal(float a, float b); 
int routine2_test(float, float);

void routine2_vec(float alpha, float beta);

__declspec(align(64)) float  test2[N];
__declspec(align(64)) float A[N][N], x[N], w[N];


int main() {

    float alpha = 0.023f, beta = 0.045f;
    double run_time, start_time;
    unsigned int t;

    initialize();

    printf("\nRoutine2:");
    start_time = omp_get_wtime(); //start timer

    for (t = 0; t < TIMES2; t++){
        // routine2(alpha, beta);
        routine2_vec(alpha, beta);
        routine2_test(alpha, beta);
}

    run_time = omp_get_wtime() - start_time; //end timer
    printf("\n Time elapsed is %f secs \n %e FLOPs achieved\n", run_time, (double)(ARITHMETIC_OPERATIONS2) / ((double)run_time / TIMES2));

    return 0;
}


void initialize() {

    unsigned int i, j;

    //initialize routine2 arrays
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            A[i][j] = (i % 99) + (j % 14) + 0.013f;
        }

    //initialize routine2 arrays
    for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        x[i] = (i % 19) - 0.01f;
        w[i] = (i % 5) - 0.002f;
        test2[i]= (i % 5) - 0.002f;
    }
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [Debugging Guide](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nodebugging/)

Comment: Please add your results to the question, along with the corresponding input.

Comment: @PaulSanders just added the remaining part.

Comment: 1. You compute a full vector but then only store a single float (`_mm_store_ss`) without first doing a [horizontal sum](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-sse-vector-sum-or-other-reduction). 2. You need to  accumulate the the partial results for all `j` in one `w[i]`. The vectorized version attempts to read/write four `w` entries per inner loop, effectively scattering the partial results across those

Comment: BTW: Since you subtract `beta` without any scaling factor each time in the innermost loop, you can simply subtract `beta * N` once in the outer loop; assuming this is even what you want that looks somewhat weird.

Comment: That's a lot of code and not much text. You might want to think about ways you can reduce the code and ways you can explain more in text. Otherwise, you might find a lot of people either skipping your question or voting down then skipping your question.

Comment: This is a matrix-vector product with some extra scaling and an offset.  You're effectively doing a dot-product of `x[]` with an `A[i]` row for each `w[i]` output.  As @Homer512 says, you need a horizontal sum at the end of the inner loop.  (And you don't need to keep storing and reloading, optimize it to `w[i] -= scaled_dot_product(A[i], x)` with a temporary vector accumulator.)  You might unroll the outer loop by four `i` values, so each vector of `x[j+0..3]` data gets used with four different vectors of `A[i][j+0..3]`, updating four accumulators.  Four hsums can share some shuffles.

Comment: Since you're already pretending FP math is associative to vectorize this, you can factor out `alpha` as well as `beta`.  `w[i] -= N*beta + alpha * dot_product(A[i], x, N)` .  See [AVX2: Computing dot product of 512 float arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59494745) for a working dot product with intrinsics.  (And [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45113527) for general optimization advice for it and links to other examples.)

Comment: Is this supposed to be a benchmark?  With `alpha` and `beta` there just to increase computational intensity (amount of work per load/store)?  If so, yeah you can do that with intrinsics and compilers probably won't hoist it out, although you'd want to check the asm (or performance counters) to make sure.

Comment: `__declspec(align(64))` isn't portable. Use `alignas(64) float x[N], ...` in C++11 or later; there's no reason to use compiler-specific alignment directives.

Comment: Obviously the reason why your two codes don't produce the same result is that one (or both) of them has a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can start by optimizing the scalar version.

1. Avoid redundant loads and stores.
2. Hoist the alpha and beta out of the innermost loop

```cpp
void routine2(float alpha, float beta) {
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        float dot = 0.f;
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < N; j++)
            dot += A[i][j] * x[j];
        w[i] += alpha * dot - N * beta;
    }
}
```

The way `beta` is used looks suspicious but that is for you to decide.

Now we vectorize. You didn't write a proper reduction loop. Here is how it should look like:

```cpp
void routine2_vec(float alpha, float beta) {
    assert(N % 4 == 0);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        __m128 dot4 = _mm_setzero_ps();
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < N; j += 4) {
            __m128 aij = _mm_loadu_ps(&A[i][j]);
            __m128 xj = _mm_loadu_ps(&x[j]);
            __m128 mres = _mm_mul_ps(aij, xj);
            dot4 = _mm_add_ps(dot4, mres);
        }
        // Reduce to two
        __m128 high = _mm_shuffle_ps(dot4, dot4, _MM_SHUFFLE(3, 3, 1, 1));
        dot4 = _mm_add_ps(dot4, high);
        // reduce to one
        high = _mm_movehl_ps(dot4, dot4);
        dot4 = _mm_add_ss(dot4, high);
        /*
         * There is no point in doing the last part with intrinsics,
         * just let the compiler handle it
         */
        float dot = _mm_cvtss_f32(dot4);
        w[i] += alpha * dot - N * beta;
    }
}
```

Discussions on the best way to do the reduction step can be found here: [Fastest way to do horizontal SSE vector sum (or other reduction)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6996764/fastest-way-to-do-horizontal-sse-vector-sum-or-other-reduction)

Since you are doing essentially a matrix-vector product, you can instead compute four values along the outer loop. This avoids choking on the loop-carried dependency chain through the accumulator as discussed here: [Why does mulss take only 3 cycles on Haswell, different from Agner's instruction tables? (Unrolling FP loops with multiple accumulators)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45113527/why-does-mulss-take-only-3-cycles-on-haswell-different-from-agners-instruction)

```cpp
static inline __m128 hadd(__m128 a, __m128 b) {
# ifdef __SSE3__
    return _mm_hadd_ps(a, b);
# else
    __m128 evens = _mm_shuffle_ps(a, b, _MM_SHUFFLE(2,0,2,0));
    __m128 odds  = _mm_shuffle_ps(a, b, _MM_SHUFFLE(3,1,3,1));
    return _mm_add_ps(evens, odds);
# endif
}

void routine2_vec(float alpha, float beta) {
    __m128 alpha2 = _mm_set1_ps(alpha);
    __m128 beta_n = _mm_set1_ps(N * beta);
    assert(N % 4 == 0);
    for (unsigned i = 0; i < N; i += 4) {
        __m128 dot4_1 = _mm_setzero_ps();
        __m128 dot4_2 = dot4_1, dot4_3 = dot4_1, dot4_4 = dot4_1;
        for (unsigned j = 0; j < N; j += 4) {
            __m128 aij = _mm_loadu_ps(&A[i][j]);
            __m128 xj = _mm_loadu_ps(&x[j]);
            __m128 mres = _mm_mul_ps(aij, xj);
            dot4_1 = _mm_add_ps(dot4_1, mres);

            aij = _mm_loadu_ps(&A[i + 1][j]);
            mres = _mm_mul_ps(aij, xj);
            dot4_2 = _mm_add_ps(dot4_2, mres);

            aij = _mm_loadu_ps(&A[i + 2][j]);
            mres = _mm_mul_ps(aij, xj);
            dot4_3 = _mm_add_ps(dot4_3, mres);

            aij = _mm_loadu_ps(&A[i + 3][j]);
            mres = _mm_mul_ps(aij, xj);
            dot4_4 = _mm_add_ps(dot4_4, mres);
        }
        /*
         * Reduce to one vector for 4 i-values
         *
         * Same as this, but faster:
         * _MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS(dot4_1, dot4_2, dot4_3, dot4_4);
         * dot4_1 = _mm_add_ps(dot4_1, dot4_2);
         * dot4_3 = _mm_add_ps(dot4_3, dot4_4);
         * dot4_1 = _mm_add_ps(dot4_1, dot4_3);
         */
        dot4_1 = hadd(dot4_1, dot4_2);
        dot4_3 = hadd(dot4_3, dot4_4);
        dot4_1 = hadd(dot4_1, dot4_3);

        dot4_1 = _mm_mul_ps(dot4_1, alpha2);
        dot4_1 = _mm_sub_ps(dot4_1, beta_n);
        __m128 wi = _mm_loadu_ps(&w[i]);
        wi = _mm_add_ps(wi, dot4_1);
        _mm_storeu_ps(&w[i], wi);
    }
}
```

Further improvements such as micro-optimizing the loop conditions or aligning one of the inputs can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77574422/how-does-simd-avx-processing-work-for-example-if-i-want-10-32-bit-floats-how/77586123#77586123). That also includes code for dealing with the tail of the array if the array size is not a multiple of 4.

Comment: If you're going to unroll, unrolling over 4 `i` values gives you 1.25 loads per mul+add instead of 2.  And it lets you share cleanup work to produce a vector of `w[i+0..3]`, e.g. with 3x `haddps` (or the SSE1 equivalent with shufps) for 6 shuffles and 3 adds per 4 outputs, instead of doing them separately with 2 shuffles + 2 adds per output = 8 each per 4 output.   (And you can vectorize the alpha and beta scaling.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Bah, of course! So much better

Comment: Re: variable-name choice: `alpha2` implies `alpha*2` or `alpha*alpha`.  I prefer `__m128 valpha` or `alphav` for naming vectors that are just broadcasts of a named scalar.  Or `alpha_bcast` or `vec_alpha` if I want a more verbose name and/or a `v` looks weird next to the other letters.

Comment: Reducing as you transpose is more efficient than doing a full 4x4 transpose (8 shuffles) before the 3 adds.  https://godbolt.org/z/914hYTbej shows an `hsum4` that's 6x `shufps` and fewer `movaps` than using `_MM_TRANSPOSE4_PS`.  And to verify correctness, clang can optimize it into 3x `haddps` if SSE3 is available.

Comment: @PeterCordes thanks for the transposition trick! Nice to see `hadd` being actually useful for something other than code-size for once. Re. variable names: I agree that `alpha2` is sub-optimal. I'm sticking with it because OP named the variable like that and changing it isn't necessary for fixing the issue. Otherwise, yes, `v_alpha` or `alpha4` would be my first choices

Comment: Oh, I hadn't noticed the OP's choice.  SO answer can point out coding-style improvements as well as correctness and performance, especially if that wouldn't make the comments too cluttered.

Comment: I just checked https://uops.info/ to see if 128-bit `haddps` was slower on AMD like the YMM version.  Unfortunately it's 4 front-end uops on Zen1 through Zen4 (but still only 3 back-end).  It has 2 cycle throughput which doesn't make sense; the port breakdown shows the shuffles should be able to run on more than 1 port... except where there are multiple dep chains, then they only pick ports 1 and 2 on Zen 3 it seems.  On Intel, shufps can run on p15 on Ice Lake and later, but the shuffle uops from haddps are 2p5.  That's fine for this, OoO exec can hide it.  Alder Lake E-cores have 3c tput.

Comment: In a use-case where there was any port-5 pressure in the inner loop body, you might choose shuffles that weren't equivalent to `haddps`.  But that might require some `movaps` register copies for a build without AVX1.

Comment: Don't use narrow `unsigned` loop counters: that forces zero-extension inside the inner loop, unlike with `int` counters where assumption of no signed-overflow UB allows promotion to pointer width, or `size_t` which is already pointer-width.  https://godbolt.org/z/j3s89K3rM - note the `mov eax, edx` / `sal rax, 2` for indexing and `add edx, 4` to increment `j`. Or similar weirdness with a `long N` function arg.  (I commented out the assert; in a debug build it might be able to optimize knowing it was a multiple of 4.  Or with compile-time-constant N.) https://godbolt.org/z/nsM3asrex with size_t

Comment: (Probably the OP had global arrays and a `#define` for N. since they also didn't take them as function args either.  But for future readers, a function that works well with runtime-variable array sizes is good.)