# x86 Intrinsic: optimize a Matrix multiply of complex floats

Tags: c, x86, matrix-multiplication, complex-numbers, avx

The following code is used to multiply a complex float matrix (separate Real,Imag) by float matrix.

I'm quite sure it can be optimized by reorder of the code due to latency of load,store and multiply.
Can you tell if there are rules how to optimize the code to handle this latency ?

```
/***************************************************************************************/
void CVector::MatrixMultiply(float* pReA, float* pImA,
                            float* pTranB,
                            float* pOutRe, float* pOutIm,
                            uint32_t RowsA, uint32_t ColsA,
                            uint32_t RowsB, uint32_t ColsB)
{
    float *pSrcReA;
    float* pSrcImA;
    float* pSrcB;
    float* pDstRe = pOutRe;
    float* pDstIm = pOutIm;
    float* pRowReA, * pRowImA;

    __m256 ReSum, ImSum, VecReA, VecImA;
    __m256 *pAvec, *pBvec;
    __m256 VecA, VecB;
    __m128 Low, High, Sum128;
    __m128 Zero128 = _mm_set_ps1(0);

    uint32_t Offset;

    for (int i = 0; i < RowsA; i++)
    {
        Offset = ColsA * i;
        pSrcReA = pReA + Offset;
        pSrcImA = pImA + Offset;
        for (int j = 0; j < ColsB; j++)
        {
            ReSum = _mm256_set1_ps(0);
            ImSum = ReSum;
            pRowReA = pSrcReA;
            pRowImA = pSrcImA;
            pSrcB = pTranB + RowsB * j;

            for (int k = 0; k < (ColsA >> 3); k++)
            {
                VecReA = _mm256_load_ps((float*)pRowReA);
                VecImA = _mm256_load_ps((float*)pRowImA);
                VecB = _mm256_load_ps((float*)pSrcB);

                ReSum = _mm256_fmadd_ps (VecReA, VecB, ReSum);
                ImSum = _mm256_fmadd_ps (VecImA, VecB, ImSum);

                pRowReA += 8;
                pRowImA += 8;
            }

            Low = _mm256_extractf128_ps(ReSum, 0);
            High = _mm256_extractf128_ps(ReSum, 1);
            Sum128 = _mm_add_ps(Low, High);
            Sum128 = _mm_hadd_ps(Sum128, Zero128);
            Sum128 = _mm_hadd_ps(Sum128, Zero128);
            *pDstRe = _mm_cvtss_f32(Sum128);

            Low = _mm256_extractf128_ps(ImSum, 0);
            High = _mm256_extractf128_ps(ImSum, 1);
            Sum128 = _mm_add_ps(Low, High);
            Sum128 = _mm_hadd_ps(Sum128, Zero128);
            Sum128 = _mm_hadd_ps(Sum128, Zero128);
            *pDstIm = _mm_cvtss_f32(Sum128);

            pDstRe++;
            pDstIm++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Like I told you last question, the product of two complex numbers isn't `re_a * re_b  + i(im_a * im_b)`, but that's what you're doing here.  A dot-product of two vectors of complex numbers is the sum of the complex products of each element.  https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexMultiplication.html .  So before you optimize, either fix your code or be absolutely sure that you just want two separate matrix products, one you're calling "real" and one "imaginary", without using complex arithmetic for the multiplies.

Comment: Fixing the multiplication doesn't change the loop structure or anything, and *adding* complex numbers is just adding the real parts and imaginary parts separately, so just the inner loop body has to change if you want to do a standard complex matmul: you will indeed end up with two SIMD vectors that each need to be summed horizontally.  See [How to vectorize a vector-matrix product with SSE?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77687986) for efficient ways to hsum (or to do 4 hsums at once to get a vector of 4 results, from one xposed column of one matrix * 4 rows of the other.)

Comment: @PeterCordes I think its performing a scalar multiplication kz as there are only real values given for the transposed B matrix. I haven't tested it to see if it works, but if it does, this should probably be posted on the code review site instead,

Comment: @SimonGoater: Oh I see, yeah that appears to be intentional with the text saying complex float matrix times float matrix.  So yeah I think this is correct for that case, effectively a complex matrix with imaginary part = 0.  With the original question title not being specific, and the code having a ton of similar short variable names, that wasn't obvious and I missed it in the text.

Answer (score 1):

The biggest performance issue with your code is that (on most CPUs) `fmadd` has a latency of 4-5 cycles, but a reciprocal throughput of 0.5 (i.e., there can be two independent FMAs performed simultaneously) -- source: [uops.info](https://uops.info/html-instr/VFMADD132PS_YMM_YMM_YMM.html).

To get the full throughput, you need to perform 8 (or on some CPUs 10) independent FMA operations inside the inner loop. E.g., have 8 independent `ReSum0..3`, `ImSum0..3` accumulators and accumulate to them by 8 `{VecReA, VecImA} * VecB0..3` products. I'm not writing this out, since I don't fully understand your code, e.g., why are you not incrementing `pSrcB` in the `k`-loop? And are you sure that `ColsA==RowsB` and that they are a multiple of 8?

Comment: chtz - Thank you very much for your reply. ColsA==RowsB. Both are multiple of 8. The inner k loop is responsible for scalar multiply of row(A).*column(B). The output of each k loop is one float element in the output. The B parameter is assumed to be transpose of the original B.

Comment: Still `pSrcB` only depends on `j` but neither on `i` or `k`, so you can't possibly cover the entire B matrix (unless `RowsB==8`)